# Package for drawing cell decompositions/cell complexes/triangulations

Tags: diagrams

Is there a package that helps to draw abstract gluings such as those used for cell complexes/triangulations in topology?

[image]

(Tetrahedral triangulation of a sphere)

[image]

(Torus)